# linux не работает wifi

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-mint

Здравствуйте! Установил linux mint, но не видит wifi сети. Посмотрел в windows модель wifi адаптера, это оказался **Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377**
Нашёл для неё драйвера на линукс по ссылке https://github.com/ajaybhatia/Qualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377-Wifi-Linux и выполнил их установку по Readme. Но, к сожалению, не помогло.
Представляю список команд и их вывода, которые помогут разобраться в проблеме:

**ifconfig -a**

```html
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a8:1e:84:0d:b3:26  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:151072 (151.0 KB)  TX bytes:151072 (151.0 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:00:e3:bf:61:e5  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**inxi -N**

```html
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 driver: ath10k_pci
           Card-3: Atheros
```

**rfkill list all**

```html
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
```

**lspci -vnn**

```html
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [17aa:3806]
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
 Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake Integrated Graphics [17aa:39fd]
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
 Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
 Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
 Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
 Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
 Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
 Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [100] #1b
 Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
 Capabilities: [300] #13
 Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
 Kernel modules: i915_bpo

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [17aa:3819]
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
 Memory at d1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
 Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [17aa:3806]
 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
 Memory at d142a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [17aa:3806]
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
 Memory at d142c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Kernel driver in use: mei_me
 Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [17aa:3806]
 Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
 Memory at d1428000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
 Memory at d1431000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
 I/O ports at f080 [size=8]
 I/O ports at f088 [size=4]
 I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
 Memory at d142f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
 Kernel driver in use: ahci
 Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d10] (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
 Memory behind bridge: d1300000-d13fffff
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000bfffffff
 Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3806]
 Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
 Capabilities: [220] #19
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d14] (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
 Memory behind bridge: d1200000-d12fffff
 Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [17aa:3806]
 Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
 Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
 Capabilities: [220] #19
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d15] (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
 Memory behind bridge: d1000000-d11fffff
 Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [17aa:3806]
 Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [100] #00
 Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
 Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
 Capabilities: [220] #19
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [17aa:3806]
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PMC [17aa:3806]
 Flags: fast devsel
 Memory at d1424000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [17aa:3812]
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 130
 Memory at d1420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Memory at d1410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [17aa:3806]
 Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
 Memory at d1430000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
 I/O ports at 1000 [disabled] [size=32]
 Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
 !!! Unknown header type 7f
 Kernel driver in use: radeon
 Kernel modules: radeon

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
 Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3820]
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
 I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
 Memory at d1204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
 Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
 Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
 Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
 Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
 Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
 Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
 Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
 Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
 Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
 Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
 Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
 Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: "Hard blocked: yes" - заблокировано, например, выключателем на клавиатуре.

Comment: Тоже обратил на это внимание. На клавиатуре на клавише F7 есть переключалка в "Режим полета", пробовал на неё нажимать (вместе с Fn и без) и проверять статус, но он не менялся.

Comment: думаю нужно выполнить " rfkill unblock ideapad_wlan"

Comment: При выполнении выдаёт "Bogus unlock argument 'ideapad_wlan'". Кстати, переключалка режима полёта срабатывает, она включает/выключает Soft blocked, а на Hard blocked не влияет

Comment: Пробовал rfkill unblock all, но все то же

Comment: я надеюсь от рута команда выполнялась? я такое видел один раз. Там ещё нужно было драйвера доставить и firmware.

Comment: От рута, разумеется. Неудобно что-либо ставить, когда нет доступа к интернету. Приходится запускать windows, качать на флешку и переключаться на линукс. Драйвера на карту уже пробовал ставить. Поищу еще советов на форумах

Comment: там ещё есть такой пакет как linux-firmware (имя не точно, нужно смотреть). а ещё бывают пакеты с блобами для драйвера.

Comment: я думаю, вывод `$ lspci -vnn` в данном случае не помешал бы.

Comment: linux-firmare пишет, что уже установлен последней версии.

Comment: добавил вывод `lspci -vnn`

Comment: @KoVadim, нет, это известная проблема некоторых лэптопов IdeaPad.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло следующее:

> sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop

Ну а чтобы не выполнять команду после каждой перезагрузки: прописал в файл `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` строку `blacklist ideapad_laptop`

Comment: И это неправильное решение. Посмотрите, нет ли упоминания вашей модели в исходниках последней версии драйвера ideapad_laptop. А ещё лучше выложите DMI информацию, поправим драйвер в ядре если нужно.

Comment: Неправильное, но зато работает. Скажите, как получить эту DMI информацию, я выложу

Comment: Запустите `dmidecode` и сохраните весь вывод в каком-нибудь файле. Расшарьте файл. Так же укажите полное и точное название таблетки или лэптопа.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9z9g1j768jxr80l/dmi.txt?dl=0
Ноутбук LENOVO V310-15ISK (https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/mobile/notebooks/410802/)

Comment: Вы сможете собрать ядро (драйвер) из исходников и проверить? Так же было бы неплохо ваш email, тогда я смог бы добавить его в патчи в рассылке и видно было бы прогресс.

Comment: Дерево исходников ядра здесь: http://git.infradead.org/linux-platform-drivers-x86.git/shortlog/refs/heads/ideapad-laptop, сам патч - здесь: http://git.infradead.org/linux-platform-drivers-x86.git/commitdiff/7dedb1f9c719a6439a2373c4a8cc5e5a9f4cd7f8